# How to enable plpython3u on macOS?

Tags: postgresql, macos, plpgsql

When running the below

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u
```

I get this

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/Library/PostgreSQL/14/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so": dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/14/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so, 0x000A): Library not loaded: /Library/edb/languagepack/v2/Python-3.9/lib/libpython3.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/14/lib/postgresql/plpython3.so
  Reason: tried: '/Library/edb/languagepack/v2/Python-3.9/lib/libpython3.9.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpython3.9.dylib' (no such file)
SQL state: 58P01
```

- MacOS Monterey  12.0.1
- pgAdmin 4       5.7
- PostgresSQL 14
- Python          3.9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install Postgres with the EDB installer from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads,
you can then choose to launch the Stack Builder after installation completes to then install "EDB Language Pack v2.0-1".

I don't have a solution for Homebrew at the moment, but will update if I find one.

Comment: You *must* also install Postgres itself with EDB to use Stack Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you install PostgreSQL on macOS with the postgresapp (https://postgresapp.com/), the instructions are at https://postgresapp.com/documentation/plpython.html.

In your case, since your Python 3.9 is the version expected for the PostgreSQL version you have (14), so you just have to execute:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```